# Bind Enum value to Label XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I'm using a Enum field to follow the state of my program.

```
public enum StatiMacchina {
        InAvvio = 1,
        Pronta = 2,
        InLavorazione = 3,
        InMovimento = 4,
        InAttesa = 5,
        InErrore = 6
}
```

I would to bind the state of the follow field (in the main window)

```
public StatiMacchina StatoMacchina { get; set; }
```

with a label in XAML.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StatoMacchina, Converter={StaticResource StatoMacchinaToString}}" />
```

I use a converter (below the Convert function)

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        switch ((StatiMacchina)value) {
            case StatiMacchina.InAvvio: return "txt1";
            case StatiMacchina.Pronta: return "txt2";
            case StatiMacchina.InLavorazione: return "txt3";
            case StatiMacchina.InMovimento: return "txt4";
            case StatiMacchina.InAttesa: return "txt5";
            case StatiMacchina.InErrore: return "txt6";
            default: return "Oppss";
        }
    }
```

When my program start the label contains the correct value, but when I update the state of the StatoMacchina variable, the label doesn't get the refresh.
What can I do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now your UI has no way of knowing that anything has changed.

You need to use `INotifyPropertyChaged`. You should pull the property from your code behind and put it in a ViewModel that is the DataContext of your window. That ViewModel will implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChaged`. Below is all you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChaged`.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

You need to expand the setter of your property to set the value then fire an OnPropertyChanged event. like so..

```
public StatiMacchina StatoMacchina { 
    get; 
    set{
       backingVariable = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
    } 
}
```

This will fire an event that your UI can listen for by changing your xaml to this.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StatoMacchina, Converter={StaticResource StatoMacchinaToString}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("StatoMacchina")`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Forgot to include my recommended implementation of OnPropertyChanged. If you use the [CallerMemberName] tag you don't have to specify the name of the property

Comment: @rmn32 You're too quick for me! I hadn't seen that `CallerMemberName` attribute thing before; the main project I work on is still .NET 4.0 because reasons. That's pretty cool.