# How to pass variable in model to view?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, model

This is my code in my model, I want to use the variable **lat** to my view. Is there a way to use it there?

The string has a lat and lng with it. What I want to happen is when the string is selected in the text the lat and lng is selected as well but it will be stored in the variable and I will use it in the view and pass it to the script where it will view it in the google map api.

```
 public IEnumerable<String> GetStartList()
            {
                //int count = 0;
                var result = new List<String>(10);
                string query = "SELECT PlaceName, Lat, Lng from Places";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var mystring = dr.GetString(0);
                        var lat = dr.GetDouble(1);
                        result.Add(mystring);
                        //result.Add(lat.ToString());
                        //count++;

                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: You could make Lat a property and then using binding in the WPF to bind your control to the Lat property.

Comment: how can i do that? by using  a stored procedure? sorry Im really new to this

Comment: Check out my answer to this question. In your case you wouldn't need a converter. You would just save lat to a property and bind that property using XAML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769120/bind-enum-value-to-label-xaml/32769199#32769199

Answer (score 0):

Data queries should be in a separate repository.

However if you are passing back just the two strings add both of them to a parent list

```
IList<IList> model = new List<IList>();
//code to get lat and result
model.add(result);
model.add(lat);
return View(model);
```

Then in the View, parse the model using Razor.

```
@model List<IList>
//... body before using model
@foreach (var lat in model[1]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

- In action

  ```
      int model = 0;
      return View(model);
  ```
- In View

  @model int
  @{
      //Layout = null;
  }
  @if(Model == 0)
  {
      //You'r Code
  }